# How to save state of React page on reload or redirecting back/ forward?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-navigation, react-props

Below is my code. I am consuming an API and getting some data on the current page. Now I want to save this page's state when I reload the page or go back or go forward again.

Here, I am getting featureGroupID from previous page api and storing here in global variable customerID.

I know it is done using local Storage but since I am extremely new on Reactjs, I dont know how to preserve the state. Can someone help?

```html
class CustomerList extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    users: [],
    error: null,
    customerID: null
    };
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/entity/getEntityByFeatureGroup/'+this.customerID)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
       this.setState({
       users: data,
       isLoading: false,
    })
      ).catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
 }
    render() {  
  var logTable = this.props;
  console.log(logTable);
      var customerColumnList = this.props;
      this.customerID = customerColumnList.location.aboutProps.id.featureGroupID;
      var headerName = customerColumnList.location.aboutProps.name.logTable.headerName;    
    const { isLoading, users, error } = this.state;
    return (....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem` for accessing local storage. like:

```html
class CustomerList extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    users: [],
    error: null,
    customerID: null
    };
    componentDidMount() {
     if(!localStorage.getItem('customerlist-data')) {
        
fetch('http://localhost:8080/entity/getEntityByFeatureGroup/'+this.customerID)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
       this.setState({
       users: data,
       isLoading: false,
    });
       localStorage.setItem('customerlist-data', data);
      }
      ).catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
     enter code here}          
    }
    render() {      
        var logTable = this.props;
        console.log(logTable);
      var customerColumnList = this.props;
      this.customerID = customerColumnList.location.aboutProps.id.featureGroupID;
      var headerName = customerColumnList.location.aboutProps.name.logTable.headerName;    
    const { isLoading, users, error } = this.state;
    return (....
```

Comment: The if condition inside componetDidMount doesn't work and is giving an error

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data + current time and conditionally take the local data or fetch from the server again.

For example, we can decide that if we have data stored locally AND an hour is not passed yet, we display the local data, otherwise we fetch from the server.

Here is a rough example

```
const storageKey = "myData";
const toHour = ms => Number((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(2));

const storeDataLocally = data => {
  const dataObj = {
    date: Date.now(),
    data
  };
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(dataObj));
};

const getDataLocally = () => {
  const dataObj = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  return JSON.parse(dataObj);
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  getDataFromServer = () => {
    console.log("from server");
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        storeDataLocally(data);
        this.setState({ data });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const localObj = getDataLocally();
    let shouldGetDataFromserver = false;
    if (localObj) {
      const isOneHourAgo =
        toHour(new Date()) - toHour(Number(localObj.date)) > 1;
      if (isOneHourAgo) {
        shouldGetDataFromserver = true;
      }
    } else {
      shouldGetDataFromserver = true;
    }

    shouldGetDataFromserver
      ? this.getDataFromServer()
      : this.setState({ data: localObj.data });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(user => (
          <div key={user.id}>{user.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```